# How to split a list to add delimiters

Tags: python, list, split, delimiter

I want to add commas as separators except for the last pair of words using python. I believe I should split the list but not sure where to start.

def main():

```
word = input('Enter next word or quit: ')
store_words = [word]
while word != 'quit':
    if word == 'quit':
        break
    word = input('Enter next word or quit: ')
    store_words.append(word)
    
store_words.remove('quit')
print(*store_words, sep=',')
```

main()

[image]

I've tried splitting the list, but it states that the list has no attribute split. I did more researching and some suggested to open a file and use readline.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After you remove `'quit'` from the list, add and/or modify the following lines as you see fit.

```
my_string = ','.join(store_words)
index = my_string.rfind(',')
my_string = my_string[0:index] + " and " + my_string[index + 1:]
print(my_string)
```

Example session:

```
Enter next word or quit: green
Enter next word or quit: eggs
Enter next word or quit: ham
Enter next word or quit: quit
green,eggs and ham
```

I hope this helps. Please let me know if there are any questions.

Answer (score 1):

For the main part of your question, try using a [`join`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#str.join) command:

```
print(', '.join(store_words[:-1]) + " and " + store_words[-1])
```

Also note, that you can write your loop in fewer lines.
Having `if word == 'quit': break` as the first line inside your `while word != 'quit':` loop doesn't do anything because it will only be called when `word != 'quit' is True`. Instead, consider something like this:

```
word = input('Enter next word or quit: ')
store_words = [word]
while word != 'quit':
    word = input('Enter next word or quit: ')
    if word != 'quit':
        store_words.append(word)
```